# C# Strong typed "sender" of events with inheritance

Tags: c#, events, generics, inheritance

I'm not sure if that is possible in C# but I would like to have events in an abstract class with a strong typed 'sender' argument.

There is my code

```
abstract class Base
{
    public degate void MyDelegate(Base sender, object arg);
    public event MyDelegate SomeEvent;

    protected void RaiseSomeEvent(object arg)
    {
        if (SomeEvent != null)
            SomeEvent(this, arg)
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    // ?
}

var obj = new Derived();
obj += EventHandler;

public void EventHandler(Derived sender, object arg)
{

}
```

So is that possible by manipuling generic where clause for example ?

Comment: Did you try to run this code?

Comment: The compiler say that EventHandler has not the correct signature for the delegate MyDelegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could definitely make it generic - but you wouldn't really want to in the case that you've given.

`Base.SomeEvent` doesn't "know" (at compile-time) what type it is - so you can't make it depend on some type parameter which will be "the right type". You *could* do something horrible like:

```
abstract class Base<T> where T : Base
{
    delegate void MyDelegate(T sender, object arg);

    public event MyDelegate SomeEvent;

    protected void RaiseSomeEvent(object arg)
    {
        if (SomeEvent != null)
            SomeEvent((T) this, arg)
    } 
}
```

(You may need `(T) (object) this` to keep the compiler happy.)

And then:

```
class Derived : Base<Derived>
```

but it gets very ugly, and there's nothing to stop this from happening:

```
class Evil : Base<Derived>
```

At that point, the cast will fail when the event is raised.

I would suggest that if you really want to be sure that the sender is the right type, you ignore the `sender` parameter and capture the variable you're using to subscribe in the first place:

```
Derived derived = new Derived();
derived.SomeEvent += (ignored, arg) => DoSomething(derived, arg);
```

Comment: But if I use anonymous method then I can't unsubscribe the method, and it's absolute needed in my program.
I find the solution with the generic class more viable in my point of view, checking if the generic type is the good one is not a big deal, I can simply do it with a routine using Reflection on assembly load.

Comment: But I'm still stucked if I have something like AnotherDerived : Derived, I won't have SomeEvent => (AnotherDerived,object) but SomeEvent => (Derived,object). And if Derived become Derived<T> I won't be able to instance it like new Derived(), but new Derived<Derived>() and that is so ugly.

Comment: After some research I've decided to implant my own Event system similar on WPF Routed Events, and though reflection I'll cast my argument properly.

Comment: You *can* unsubscribe handlers created with anonymous methods - you just need to retain a reference to the handler. In terms of the "grandchild" part, you would need to make `Derived` generic too (with an additional constraint). But yes, it's ugly - you're trying to do something which is very rarely elegant.